# Connection Reset error trying to set up HTTPS locally using VS and IIS Express

Tags: iis, ssl, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I'm trying to set up Facebook authentication on my application, so I tried following the steps at this page: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

I'm specifically under the section labeled "Setting up SSL in the Project"

I set SSL Enabled to true on my project, updated the Project URL in the project properties, and added the RequireHttps annotation to my Home Controller

[image]

Everything builds fine, but when I go to view my site, it just doesn't work and I get a "connection reset" message:

[image]

If I change the settings back, then everything works fine. I also double-checked my certificates, and all I have locally is the one that IIS Express created for my application

[image]

I'm kind of at a loss here, am I missing something simple?

Comment: Answered Similar question here(http://goo.gl/MyDrNM) at SO - and you can read the MS post at http://goo.gl/Kmimd2

Answer (score 7):

try to put a port in the range 44300-44399 this one hundred port numbers already have a certificate "bound" to them

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind https to your website. I would recommend installing the full version of IIS if you want to have appropriate control over the website. I'm also guessing that you will be deploying the code to this version of IIS.

**Install IIS**

Search for "Turn Windows Features On or Off" and look for "Internet Information Services". It should select a base install by default, then install what you need under "Application Development Features".

**Bind HTTPS in IIS**

After you've created your website in IIS, select/highlight the site from the left tree view. On the right of the window you will see "Bindings". Select, click add, change type https and you should be able to select the IIS Express Development certificate from the drop down.

**Change server within Visual Studio**

Within the project properties under Web, select "Local IIS" from the drop down.